# Catchall for any string

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Scripts. My program is supposed to look for a string within a range, and then print what it finds to a document.

The problem that I am facing is that I can query for specific strings, but not all the strings within the range are the same. What would be a catchall for any string? An alternative would be looking for any type of 'data' within that cell.

```
    var gift = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,14).getValue();
    if (gift == '') {
      var first = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var last = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      doc.getBody().appendParagraph(first + ' ' + last);
  }
```

Comment: Try using [Range.createTextFinder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))

Comment: You're looking  for [tag:regex]

Comment: Do you mean looking for cells whose value is a string? Could you share an example of what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers, but I ended up solving my own problem. Range.createTextFinder() was not what I was looking for, I needed an in general way of finding a non specific string. I tried regex, and I had similar issues, although I may have been using it incorrectly.

My solution was making it so that if my variable was not equal to a blank cell, it would go through the function.

```
if (gift != ''){

}
```